# Uniqueness with two fields in the same table rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to validate the uniqueness of two or more fields in the same model? For example lets say that I have fields `:name` and `:zip`. An acceptable set would be `{[name1, zip1], [name1, zip2]}`but you can't have `{[name1,zip1],[name1,zip1]}` in the same table.

Is there a rails `validates` method that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scope`:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:zip]
```

See [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) and [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness) for more information.

You can use `:scope` option to specify other attributes that are used to limit the uniqueness check.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the name can't be the same?

Comment: :name and :zip at the same time can not be the same.

Comment: "You can use :scope option to specify other attributes that are used to limit the uniqueness check." is a bit unclear. Does limit mean it makes the attributes inclusive for uniqueness?

Comment: It means that objects are grouped by `:scope` parameter and uniqueness is checked in the groups by `:name`. If the `:scope` is not specified uniqueness is checked over the whole table. In other case uniqueness is checked over the objects which have the same `:scope` parameters.

Comment: so is it legal to say `validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:zip, :name]`?

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:zip]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a validation like the others told you but you could also add an unique index to the table. That would prevent inserting duplicates on the database layer and increasre the select speed. You need to create a new migration for that `rails g migration addUniqueIndexForZipAndNameToTablename`

```
add_index :tablename, [:name, :zip], :unique => true
```

The only problem you might get is that there are MySQL Errors when you try to insert a duplicate you need to prevent that using

```
begin
  # insert,...
rescue ExceptionHere
  # do sth...
end
```